# Computing a series in terms of exponential function

Tags: recursion, series-expansion

Is there any way to compute the following series in terms of exponential function ?
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty Y_1(k)\;x^k$$ where

$$Y_1(k) = \frac{(k - 1)!}{k!}Y_3(k - 1)$$
$$Y_2(k) = \frac{(k - 1)!}{k!}Y_4(k - 1)$$
$$Y_3(k) = \frac{(k - 1)!}{k!}(1/2Y_3(k - 1) + 1/2Y_1(k - 1))$$
$$Y_4(k) = \frac{(k - 1)!}{k!}(1/2Y_4(k - 1) + 1/2Y_2(k - 1))$$
such that: 
$\;Y_1(0)= 2 + r,\; Y_2(0) = 4 - r,\; Y_3(0) = 2 + r,\; Y_4(0) = 4 - r$

```
Y1[0] := 2 + r;
Y2[0] := 4 - r;
Y3[0] := 2 + r;
Y4[0] := 4 - r;
Y1[k_] := (k - 1)!/(k!)*(Y3[k - 1]);
Y2[k_] := (k - 1)!/(k!)*(Y4[k - 1]); 
Y3[k_] := (k - 1)!/(k!)*(1/2*Y3[k - 1] + 1/2*Y1[k - 1]); 
Y4[k_] := (k - 1)!/(k!)*(1/2*Y4[k - 1] + 1/2*Y2[k - 1]);

Sum[ Y1[k] x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

Comment: Your coefficients aren't monotonic `ListLinePlot@
 Table[Table[FullSimplify[Y1[k]], {k, 0, 10}] /. r -> j, {j, 6}]`

Comment: @belisarius, This series is convergent to $(2+r)e^x$. Why can not Mathematica compute it?

Comment: Are you sure? http://i.stack.imgur.com/V1yCd.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

You changed your equations after accepting this answer. The same method works:

First we modify your functions to get some speed:

```
Y1[0] = 2 + r;
Y2[0] = 4 - r;
Y3[0] = 2 + r;
Y4[0] = 4 - r;
Y1[k_] := Y1[k] = FullSimplify[(k - 1)!/(k!)*(Y3[k - 1])];
Y2[k_] := Y2[k] = FullSimplify[(k - 1)!/(k!)*(Y4[k - 1])];
Y3[k_] := Y3[k] = FullSimplify[(k - 1)!/(k!)*(1/2*Y3[k - 1] + 1/2*Y1[k - 1])];
Y4[k_] := Y4[k] = FullSimplify[(k - 1)!/(k!)*(1/2*Y4[k - 1] + 1/2*Y2[k - 1])];
```

Now we calculate the coefficients (we take out a (2+r) factor):

```
f = FindSequenceFunction[Table[FullSimplify[Y1[i]], {i, 0, 50}], n]
(*
 (2 + r)/Pochhammer[1, -1 + n]
*)

Sum[f x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
(*
  E^x (2 + r) x
*)
```

Comment: Your codes don't work.

Comment: @Angel Check it now. There was a syntax error.

Comment: Excellent. I edited my question.Thanks a million.